# How do I organise a nested list representing coordinate-values to a coordinate-list

Tags: python, list, structure, coordinates

I would like to change my data-structure that get from my data-files in such a way that I get a list of all coordinate-values for every coordinates (so a list for all coordinates filled with values)

e.g.
for i in range (files):

#### open file

```
file_output = [[0,4,6],[9,4,1],[2,5,3]]
```

#### second loop

```
file_output = [[6,1,8],[4,7,3],[3,7,0]]
```

to

```
coordinates = [[0,6],[4,1],[6,8],[9,4],[4,7],[1,3],[2,3],[5,7],[3,0]]
```

It should be noted that I use over 1000 files of this format, which I should merge.

Comment: It should be noted that I use over 1000 files of this format, which I should merge.

Comment: Please add your *notes* with editing your question, instead of comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could also explore the built-in **[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)** function

```
>>> l = []
>>> for k,v in zip(a,b):
        l.append(zip(k,v))
>>> print l
[[0,6],[4,1],[6,8],[9,4],[4,7],[1,3],[2,3],[5,7],[3,0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have over 1000 files in this format. How should this fit into the source?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [[0,4,6],[9,4,1],[2,5,3]]
>>> b = [[6,1,8],[4,7,3],[3,7,0]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> zip(chain(*a),chain(*b))
[(0, 6), (4, 1), (6, 8), (9, 4), (4, 7), (1, 3), (2, 3), (5, 7), (3, 0)]
>>>
```

Comment: you can just loop over them and then zip them

Comment: But how do I create all the chains then?

Answer (score 0):

This should be useful.

```
[zip(i,j) for i in a for j in b]
```

However it provides list of tuples, which should satisfy your needs.

If there will only be two lists, you can use this as well.

```
[[i, j] for i in a for j in b]
```